# Why the data returned to ajax looks ok in alert but does not work when I try to put it into my html

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Here is the unworking part of my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    // ...
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // La reponse du serveur est contenu dans data
        // On peut faire ce qu'on veut avec ici
        dataA1 = data.toString();
        $("#chatprototypetext").html = dataA1;
        alert(dataA1);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // Une erreur s'est produite lors de la requete
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

I tried to change the data variable returned by ajax in the success function into a string but I think it is already a string. Apparently it does not appear in the div. I tried with .append and with document.getElementById().html but it did not worked, and I'm sure it's not a css error either as the last code in my css file is about the div id chatprototypetext. How can the be able to appear correctly in the alert but nowhere else... maybe in the console.log()... 
My php file return a bunch of echo line like this:

```
<?php
    echo "<p>" . $donnees['nickname'] . ":" . $donnees['message'] . "</p>";
?>
```

Comment: Can we see a live demo? At the moment I don't think we have enough information to help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) is a function, not a variable. You need to use it like this:

```
$("#chatprototypetext").html(dataA1);
```

Comment: Thread solved! Thank very much for your time and sorry for being so dumb... I still wonder why the document.getElementById("chatprototypetext").html = dataA1; did not work

Comment: @LordDoomer It did not work, because the variable to change the HTML of an element is `myElement.innerHTML`, not `myElement.html`. Also if his answer solved your problem, you should mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$("#chatprototypetext").html(dataA1);
```

Convert to string is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `getElementById('').innerHTML` instead of `getElementById().html`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 
    //dataA1 = data.toString();
    $("#chatprototypetext").html(data);
    alert(data);
},
```

Comment: The alert worked fine  with both data and dataA1. Thank for trying to help me but my problem was solved long ago and my ajax public chat is already working in localhost at least and where is the thread resolved button plz ?